# My xticks are pushed to the left

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot time against a percentage value, and I have a lot of measure points. I also want the x-axis to show formatted time in order for it to give an idea of then and where. The last side note is that i want less xticks than actual measure points.

My problem is, when I try to plot, my xticks are shifted to the left of the axis. See picture below

[image]

My code looks something like this

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ticks = [ctime1, ctime2, ctime3]
x = range(10)
y = range(10)
plt.xticks(x, ticks)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually expected behavior because your `x` variable contains 10 values and your `ticks` variable only contains 3. You would need to create a `tick` entry to correspond to each entry in `x` if you don't want them to appear only on the left as you've shown.

Also the other issue is that the tick text is too long so there is a lot of overlap. Maybe consider rotating the xticks as well.

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(10)
y = range(10)

# Xtick labels
ticks = [ctime(val) for val in x]
plt.plot(x,y)

# Plot ticks with a rotation
plt.xticks(x, ticks, rotation=12)

plt.show()
```

Otherwise you could plot fewer xticks.

```
import numpy as np

x = range(10)
y = range(10)

ticks = [ctime(1), ctime(2), ctime(3)]
xtickpos = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 3)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(xtickpos, ticks)
```

Comment: But I have thousands of measure points in my actual program, and having more that 5 ticks on my x-wont be very informative either. Is there no way to evenly distribute them?

Comment: @Uzzee See my last example of how to create fewer xticks

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. Originally I thought that xtickpos only corresponded to the order of x-value to display, like [1, 2, 3] for 1st 2nd 3rd. Thank you!